# Selections and Alerts

Tags: javascript, html, function, select, alert

Ok so I am trying to learn some basic javascript and html using a few different websites, when I got stuck. I have tried looking though this forum for another question like mine, but all the coding just goes right over my head and I don't understand a thing. I am trying to get the user to select a name from a drop down menu and then get that name to be printed in an alert along with a short message. This is what I have so far.

HTML

```
<select name="name">
<option value="Matthew">Matthew</option>
<option value="John">John</option>
<option value="Jared">Jared</option>
</select>
<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="Message()" />
```

Javascript

```
function Message()
{
    var name = document.getElementsByName(name).value;  
    alert("Hi " + name)
}
```

I know this is probably really simple, but I would appreciate it if you explained what I did wrong and provide a fixed version of the code.

Thanks in advance,
Matthew

Comment: Then function Message is a javascript function but not java

Answer (score 1):

**Replace**

```
.getElementsByName(name).value;
```

**with**

```
.getElementsByName('name')[0].value;
-------------------^----^-----
```

you were missing `'`.

Comment: getElementsByName return array

Comment: Thanks but one thing, whats the [0] for?

Comment: @user2717637 as javaBeginner commented `getElementsByName` return array so we are adding `[0]` to get first DOM rfom that returned array,

Comment: And the alert says undefined now, so the alert reads: Hi underfined. Any clue why?

Answer (score 0):

You should write `"name"`  not simply `name`.

It should be a string not `variable`.

Change it to

```
 var name = document.getElementsByName("name")[0].value;
```

And do not use reserved key words,They create mess some times.

Example :`<select name="userName">` not simply `<select name="name">`

Answer (score 0):

you can use it in this way

```
<select id="name">
<option value="Matthew">Matthew</option>
<option value="John">John</option>
<option value="Jared">Jared</option>
</select>
<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="Message()" />
```

and your javascript

```
function Message()
{
var name = document.getElementById('name').value;  
alert("Hi " + name)
}
```

It will work fine.